# How to conceptually understand the symmetries of the Heisenberg Antiferromagnet

Tags: symmetry, conservation-laws, hamiltonian

Consider the Heisenberg antiferromagnet's Hamiltonian:
$$
\hat{H} = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 1}^L\bigg(J_x \hat{\sigma}^x_n \hat{\sigma}^x_{n+1} + J_y \hat{\sigma}^y_n \hat{\sigma}^y_{n+1} + J_z \hat{\sigma}^z_n \hat{\sigma}^z_{n+1} + h\hat{\sigma}^z_n\bigg) \text{ where $J_x = J_y = J_z < 0$}
$$

Because of the equality of the coupling constants $J_x$ and $J_y$, there is a $U(1)$ symmetry:
$$
\hat{O}_1 = \sum_{n = 1}^L \hat{\sigma}^z_n
$$
When the external magnetic field $h$ is turned off, there is a $Z_2$ symmetry:
$$
\hat{O}_2 = \bigotimes_{n = 1}^L \hat{\sigma}^x_n
$$

I have these questions:

(1) Why is the $U(1)$ charge --- i.e. the total spin --- conserved conceptually?

(2) Conceptually, why does changing the couple constants from equality destroy the total spin conservation?

(3)What is the conserved $Z_2$ charge and why is it conserved conceptually?

(4)Conceptually, why does introducing an external field destroy the $Z_2$ charge conservation?

Comment: Are you familiar with Noether's theorem?  The U(1) rotates the $y$ and $x$ spins into each other and is clearly broken when $J_x\ne J_y$, The  $Z_2$ flips the sign of $\sigma_z$ so non-zero $h$ breaks that.

Comment: @mikestone Yes, I am familiar with Noether's theorem and I understand the mathematics behind the symmetries; however, I was thinking from a more conceptual angle. For instance, in the Bose-Hubbard model, total boson number is conserved and the conceptual reason for that is that bosons cannot leave the lattice+particle bath system. Here total spin is akin to total particle number. How does changing the couple constants allow spin to "leak out," thus destroying total spin conservation?

Comment: It is only the $z$ component of total spin that is conserved under the U(1).  When $J_x\ne J_y$, the lack of rotational symmetry allows the  transfer of  some $z$ component of  angular momentum  to the lattice.

Comment: @mikestone Thank you very much